# Mac editor with built-in side-by-side compare plugin?

Tags: macos, text-editors

I know there are many suggestions on here discussing compatible editors for a Macintosh, but I haven't found any in this regards.

What I love about Notepad++ is the "compare" plugin.  I use it for comparing java, xml, and more.  What I get in return is a side by side comparison that scroll in sync and the diffs are highlighted not placed in a separate from at the bottom that I must click on to see the difference.  Is there any editor out there for Mac that shows a side-by-side comparison with differences highlighted?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963289

Answer (score 5):

I am a fan of [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html). You can get a free version of the same called [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), which is also awesome. Both support this type of diff.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to the TextWrangler thing.

Comment: @에이바: yup. 4 more

Comment: @에이바, there's always the "delete" link!

Comment: I had TextWrangler already, so I went with that. Very good comparison tool more than what I expected it moving changes between two files a breeze. Saved me hours of work.

Comment: to compare the files `Search->Find Differences.`

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Developer Tools:

```
/Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge.app
```

Answer (score 0):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is a popular editor, but I don't know if the comparison works.

Comment: It's a color-highlighted unified `diff` (at least that's what I use). Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

[MacVim](http://macvim.org/) with VimDiff in action:

[image: VimDiff]

Just enable [scrollbind](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolling_synchronously) and you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) does a bang-up job.  I now miss npp a little less.

[image: vs code compare preview]

[Here's some instructions](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/06/04/how-to-compare-files-in-visual-studio-code/) on how to do it - it's all straightforward.

Comment: Right now this answer is a link-only answer. Including the relevant information from the link(s) so that the entire answer is here will make it more useful, and less likely to be removed.